# Can't install summarise gem on OSX, missing glib.h

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, homebrew, glib

I'm trying to install this gem, [summarize](https://github.com/ssoper/summarize), by running:

```
gem install summarise
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
...
In file included from article.c:25:
./libots.h:24:10: fatal error: 'glib.h' file not found
```

But when i try and run:

```
brew install glib
```

i get:

```
glib-2.38.2 already installed
```

Any ideas on what to try next?

---

EDIT:
I've since tried:

```
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.38.2/include/glib-2.0/
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.38.2/lib/
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.38.2/lib/pkgconfig/
```

...and that seems to have allowed me to move on to a new error:

```
compiling article.c
article.c:107:37: warning: passing 'const unsigned char *' to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
if ((aWord == NULL) || (0==strlen(aWord)) ||(NULL==aLine)) return;
                                ^~~~~
/usr/include/string.h:82:28: note: passing argument to parameter here
size_t   strlen(const char *);
                        ^
article.c:109:68: warning: passing 'const unsigned char *' to parameter of type 'const gchar *' (aka 'const char *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
aLine->words = g_list_append (aLine->words, (gpointer) g_strdup (aWord));
                                                               ^~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.38.2/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstrfuncs.h:216:52: note: passing argument to parameter 'str' here
gchar*                g_strdup         (const char *str) G_GNUC_MALLOC;
```

...

```
dictionary.c:28:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlmemory.h' file not found
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into exactly the same problem, I recommend using this gem instead: https://github.com/deepfryed/ots which provides OSX instructions, and installed on Mavericks seamlessly for me.

Comment: That's what I've ended up using. From what I can tell it does much the same job. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to install glib-devel, which will contain the source and headers for the glib library.

Comment: I've added an update to my question, how do I install `glib-revel`? `brew install glib2-devel` doesn't seem to find anything.

Comment: Looks like you need libxml-devel as well.

Comment: what's the commands for installing these? brew doesn't seem to find anything for those names

Comment: `brew install glib` will install the correct library

Comment: Also add as symlink (see https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/68): `sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2/libxml /usr/local/include/libxml`